What does the "sens" polarity symbol on a HP charger mean?
I'm trying to determine if a spare adapter I have could be a backup for this HP laptop.
The V and A are a good match, but I still don't dare to plug it in because I don't understand this icon on the original charger, and the laptop also doesn't have a traditional polarity symbol.
What is the meaning of this "sens" symbol on the original charger?
Is it even a polarity symbol?


It’s probably simpler than that, it’s a sense line, I would assume there is a + and - signal also.

The positive is on a metal ring on the inside of the circular connector with an additional pin in the center that can either communicate with the laptop or provide a known resistance or voltage so that the laptop can determine current supply capabilities.

"Sens" is a sense signal - a way for the laptop to determine whether the power supply plugged in is genuine. You can see the other symbols there.
The outer ring is the Negative/Ground connection, the inner ring is the positive connection, and the middle pin is a Sense pin. This can be or do whatever the manufacturer wants. Some laptops will not charge if you plug in a charger that doesn't use the SENSE pin in the way the laptop expects, but might still use it to power the machine. Some laptops may use it nonetheless, and use the SENSE pin for something else rather than authentication (for e.g. some batteries use a 3rd connection as a thermistor to stop charging if the battery gets too hot)
You should be careful, a lot of chargers use the middle pin for the positive signal, and understandably so - many of them don't have inner rings anyway. You need to double check the laptops polarity matches up with the chargers one.
I have had success in the past cutting the plug off a broken charger and splicing it into another charger of the right Voltage and same-or-higher max current output - but you have to follow the polarity diagram. In my case, the laptop powered on but did not charge and there was a warning displayed on boot about a non-genuine charger. I can't speak for your case, though.
